# What is NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains?

Tags: objective-c, core-foundation

```
[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]
```

I used to know that sending a message to the object is kind of calling the method. However, I can't recognize what is `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`. Is it C style function? If yes then why among all `message` style calls we have thing kind of function?

Comment: small note, since Xcode 5, you should use -firstObject instead of -lastObject for this feature.

Comment: why should one use firstObject instead of lastObject? Don't we expect there to be only one result?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it's a plain C function taking and returning objective-c objects.

As to the why... Apple probably didn't find a nice class to put it in. :-) Seriously though, it could be a static method on `UIApplication` or `NSApplication` or similar, but it's hard to justify and quite system-specific (you'd have it in `NSApplication` on OS X and `UIApplication` on iOS).

Comment: Can you please answer the comment from above: "why should one use firstObject instead of lastObject? Don't we expect there to be only one result? ".
Isn't this suppose to just be a single string-like path like /User/User_name/library/developers/...
Why is it an array?!

[Eiko sendThankYouMessage]

Comment: @asma22 No, I can't. If there's a difference, it is non-obvious. The only clue in the documentation says "The list is in the order in which you should search the directories", making firstObject the natural choice. The bigger questions are what to do if the array contains zero or more than one object. I have no good idea.

Answer (score 15):

Check out 
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Directories_on_iPhone_OS and http://iphonedevelopmentblog.blogspot.com/2011/03/documents-directory-file-path-iphone.html

I was studying the same material, and these links provide exhaustive information on the subject.